# Elixir: equivalent of scriptsIn for less files (concat + compile less files in one css file)?

Tags: css, laravel, gulp, less, laravel-elixir

I'd like to concat+compile all the less files of one folder into a specified css file.

It works well with JS scripts, using the `scriptsIn` function but I can't find an equivalent for less files.
I've read this thread: [Laravel Elixir - Compile/concat all less files into one css file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437747/laravel-elixir-compile-concat-all-less-files-into-one-css-file) but don't find it very useful since I don't want to know what's in my folder (I don't know how many different less files there are in it).

I'd like to write something like that, if possible:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.lessIn('resources/assets/less/myfolder', 'public/css/myfolder.css');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated laravel-elixir to version 5.0.0 and now this works well:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('resources/assets/less/myfolder/*.less', 'public/css/myfolder.css');
})
```